# skip row if column empty

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a problem with filter rows with empty row in 4 column.

Input:

```
1242    2021-11-22     Text     5.0
1242    2021-11-22     Text
1242    2021-11-22     Text     5.0
1242    2021-11-22     Text     5.0
4095    2021-11-22     Text
4095    2021-11-22     Text     5.0
4095    2021-11-22     Text
4095    2021-11-22     Text     5.0
4095    2021-11-22     Text
4095    2021-11-22     Text     5.0
```

and I want output:

```
1242    2021-11-22     Text     5.0
1242    2021-11-22     Text     5.0
1242    2021-11-22     Text     5.0
4095    2021-11-22     Text     5.0
4095    2021-11-22     Text     5.0
4095    2021-11-22     Text     5.0
```

The size of a file is 2.0Gb and number of lines is ~45m.

I have tried these, but none of it worked - it returns empty or same file:

```
awk -F: '{if($4 != "") print}'
awk -F '$4 != ""'
awk -F , '$4 != "\"\"" {print}'
```

Comment: What is the delimiter between columns? Space, TAB, comma?

Comment: Delimeter is TAB

Comment: When posting an example of data that includes text it's best to provide some representative text, not just use the word `Text` everywhere. If your delimiter is tab then setting your delimiter to `:` or `,` is obviously not going to work.

Answer (score 7):

```
awk 'NF==4' file
```

or if your `Text` can contain blanks then:

```
awk -F'\t' '$4!=""' file
```

If that's not all you need then edit your question to provide more truly representative sample input/output included cases that doesn't work for.

Comment: Why not just `awk '$4'`? Am I missing a failsafe?

Comment: $4 could be the non-empty value zero.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '$4 !~ /^$/' filename

1242    2021-11-22     Text     5.0
1242    2021-11-22     Text     5.0
1242    2021-11-22     Text     5.0
4095    2021-11-22     Text     5.0
4095    2021-11-22     Text     5.0
4095    2021-11-22     Text     5.0
```